# Why mysql is not working after port number of wamp is changed to 8080

Tags: wampserver

I installed wampserver to my system and after installing I tried `localhost` in the browser but it was not working.

As I also have OSGEO installed in my system and that installs a MYSQLServer.

So, I changed the port number of the wampservers Apache to 8080 and changed  mysql port from 3306 to 3307 in `my.ini`.

I changed these lines in the httpd.conf file.

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

Now wamp is working. But when I tried "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" in the browser I am getting following error:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What password are you using??? You should be using a BLANK password, as that is the default password for `root`. And PUT MYSQL back onto port 3306. **It was never a port issue**

Comment: Yes the password ir blank. And i have two mysql running so ofcourse i need to change the port. Dont just give the downvote

Comment: You did not say that you had 2 MYSQL Server running

Comment: _I changed the port number of the wamp to 8080_ WAMPServer does not have a port number...... but Apache does!!!!

Comment: Exactly which version of WAMPServer are you using

Comment: I have written i have osgeo installed as well. It has its own mysql running when i start system which is default 3306. So i need to change wamp mysql to 3307. My wampserver version is 2.5

Comment: Anyways I have fixed this problem. I didnot knew that I need to change port in php.ini as well. So changing the port in both my.ini and php.ini and some few changes that I forgot :)

Comment: That is just what I was about to suggest

Comment: You might like to use 3308 instead. When/If you upgrade to WAMPServer3.0.8+ that gives you MariaDB if you want it, and that uses 3307 by default in WAMPServer

Comment: Yes thank you for suggesting. I guess this question doesnot need downvote :)

Comment: It could definitely use an answer. Maybe you should post what you did to assist other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the OSGEO installs a MYSQL Server instance as well as WAMPServer which uses the default port 3306, it gets conflicted with MYSQL Server of WAMPServer.

I changed the port that MYSQL should use in the WAMPServer `my.ini` file to 3307

```
port = 3307
```

and in `php.ini` changed

```
mysqli.default_port = 3307
mysql.default_port = 3307
```

According to @RiggsFolly, if using wampserver version 3.0.8+, use  port 3308 instead

Comment: A bit thin on details but better than nothing